# How to handle backPress viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-tablayout

[signup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgaYX.png)  [login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7NxS.png) I implemented auth screen contains fragments (loginFragment,SignUpFramgent) using viewpager ,
the SignUpFragment contain three fragments for sign up steps 
i want to handle the back press on each of the sign up fragments as well when the user is in the first sign up fragment and press back switches to login frag

my Auth activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //assign the views
    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.authToolBar);
    viewPager=findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tableLayout=findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    //add fragments to the adapter and attact them to viewPager
    TabAdapter tabAdapter=new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new LoginFragment(),"Login");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new SignUpFragment(),"Sign Up");
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
    tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    switch (viewPager.getCurrentItem()){
        case 0:
            finish();
            return;
        case 1:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

my signUp fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false);
    //assign the views
     button=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);
     stateProgressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.your_state_progress_bar_signUp);
     fragmentManager=getChildFragmentManager();
     fragmentHelper =new FragmentHelper();
     //default fragment is PersonalInfoFragment
     if (savedInstanceState==null){

         fragment=new PersonalInfoSignUpFragment();
         fragmentHelper.setFragment(fragment,R.id.sign_up_container,fragmentManager,"personal");
         stateProgressBar.setStateDescriptionData(descriptionData);
         stateProgressBar.setCurrentStateNumber(StateProgressBar.StateNumber.ONE);
    }
    button.setOnClickListener(this);


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    progressNumber=stateProgressBar.getCurrentStateNumber();
    //on click next move to next step until the last redirect to the mainActivity
    if (v.getId()==R.id.btn_sign_up){
        switch (progressNumber){
            case 1:
                fragment=new ContactSignUpFragment();

                fragmentHelper.setFragment(fragment,R.id.sign_up_container,fragmentManager,"contacts");
                stateProgressBar.setCurrentStateNumber(StateProgressBar.StateNumber.TWO);

                return;
            case 2:
                fragment=new ShopSignUpFragment();
                fragmentHelper.setFragment(fragment,R.id.sign_up_container,fragmentManager,"shop");
                stateProgressBar.setCurrentStateNumber(StateProgressBar.StateNumber.THREE);

                return;

            case 3:
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();

                return;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1,false);
    }else{
         finish();
    }

}
```

but do not call `super.onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: Sir that did't fix the UX still when i press back from any fragment on the signup steps redirects me back to the login when i press sign up again it goes to the last fragment that i was on

Comment: I added screen shots for the login and sign up screen if you have better way to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Just don't add the Login fragment to the backstack. If you have problem in it.

If you have problem when you click on viewpagers different tabs and then press back and it will jump to all of your previous opened fragments - you can do this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (currentItem != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem - 1, true);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```